# Django rest framework swagger missing port when run in docker

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, swagger

I am using rest framework swagger for the first time in my Django application.  When I run it locally from PyCharm it works just fine.  My app runs on port 1337 and when I Try Out my restful API endpoint and click Execute, the curl command works and the URL includes the port.

The issue is when I run my Django app in a Docker.  In this case, the URL in the curl command does not include the port.  Do I have to add any swagger specific configuration to my docker compose file?  I have not changed my Dockerfile nor my docker-compose file at all.

[image: Running in docker]

What do I need to do to get this to work properly?

Comment: You should add more details. How does your docker setup, how does your drf setup etc, etc. in short, please do add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please post you Dockerfile / docker-compose.

Comment: Are you passing a `url` to `get_schema_view`?

Comment: I wasn't by I am now.   Passing url='/' did the trick, thanks. Please submit proper answer for bounty.

Comment: although this might have gotten fixed, were you using nginx?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have set the ***`url`*** parameter for the [**`get_schema_view(...)`**--(DRF Doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#get_schema_view) function. The `url` is used to set the *canonical base URL* for the schema.

If you didn't set the value, DRF will use the ***"requested host"*** as the default URL.

> #### [Ref](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/bb133522efaf6ce3ae8fdf1dec6cd79566cfd166/rest_framework/schemas/coreapi.py#L160)
>
> ```
> url = self.url
> if not url and request is not None:
>     url = request.build_absolute_uri()
> ```

SO, you can set the `url` to any value or you can exclude the parameter to get the default behavior.

```
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('openapi', get_schema_view(
        title="Your Project",
        description="API for all things …",
        version="1.0.0"
    ), name='openapi-schema'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file `urls.py` which is the place you are setting URL for SWAGGER.
Don't set `url` in get_schema_view function.
Also, when you are running the app by using docker, the URL in the curl command does not include the port -> That's right!
I think that your file is using multiple settings for swagger by checking like this:
`if getattr(settings, "SETTINGS_ENV", None) in ["local", "dev", "draft", "production"]:`